# Library not loaded error with Dropbox OS X framework

Tags: xcode, sdk, path, dropbox

I've downloaded OS X Dropbox SDK from this page https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdk

And used this instruction for iOS to add it into my project (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/setup#ios):

```
...
2. Navigate to where you uncompressed the SDK and drag the DropboxSDK.framework folder into your project in Xcode
3. Make sure Copy items into destination group's folder is selected 
...
```

When I run my app, I get this error:

> dyld: Library not loaded:
>   @executable_path/../Frameworks/DropboxOSX.framework/Versions/A/DropboxOSX
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/ksoftware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Designer_Snapper-btgmsuibcccggidhnbajjezvhhhn/Build/Products/Debug/Designer
>   Snapper.app/Contents/MacOS/Designer Snapper   Reason: image not found

The DBRouletteOSX application that was included in SDK runs and works well.

Why am I having this error, and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the documentation provided with the download is wrong. In the step where it states to add a new Build Phase to copy the files to Resources you need to copy it to Frameworks.

If you go to your Application Target, select the `Build Phases` tab the `Copy Files` part should show `Destination --> Frameworks` with `DropboxOSX.framework` as the content.

After you have done this go to `Project --> Clean` and build again this time it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, jomis! The problem was really in documentation. I carefully looked at example app provided inside frame work. And noticed `Copy Files` block.

This settings worked for me: [Xcode settings screenshot](http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/6437/12067248.37/0_7b25f_1846c840_XXL.png.jpg)